# How to set mode and time in Dynamic Agents?

Tags: instana

I am referring to this page:

https://www.instana.com/docs/setup_and_manage/host_agent/updates/#update-interval

Is there a way to pass mode and time from outside as environment variables or any other way beside logging into the pod and manually changing the files inside etc/instana/com.instana.agent.main.config.UpdateManager.cfg file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To whoever removed his/her answer: It was a correct answer. I don't know why you deleted it. Anyhow, I am posting again in case someone stumbles here.

You can control frequency and time by using `INSTANA_AGENT_UPDATES_FREQUENCY` and `INSTANA_AGENT_UPDATES_TIME` environment variables.

Updating `mode` via env variable is still unknown at this point.

Look at this page for more info: https://www.instana.com/docs/setup_and_manage/host_agent/on/docker/#updates-and-version-pinning

Answer (score 1):

Most agent settings that one may want to change quickly are available as environment variables, see https://www.instana.com/docs/setup_and_manage/host_agent/on/docker. For example, setting the mode via environment variable is supported as well with `INSTANA_AGENT_MODE`, see e.g., https://hub.docker.com/r/instana/agent. The valid values are:

- `APM`: the default, the agent monitors everything
- `INFRASTRUCTURE`: the agent will collect metrics and entities but not traces
- `OFF`: agent runs but collects no telemetry
- `AWS`: agent will collect data about AWS managed services in a region and an account, supported on EC2 and Fargate, and with some extra configurations, on hosts outside AWS

On Kubernetes, it is also of course possible to use a ConfigMap to override files in the agent container.

Comment: It would be nice to write the modes and a use case directly in your answer, in case the original link is not available.